# PHP - Button to delete Item from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am coding some video upload script and I am with the admin panel right now.
There I have a List with all Videos. And each video has one delete button on the right side.
When I click the button then this video should be deleted from database but its not working after I click the button nothing happens.

```
    <?php

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `videos`");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];

    echo "<a href='watch.php?id=$id'>$name</a><br /> 
    <input type='submit' name='remove' value='Delete'<br />";
 }

     if (isset($_POST['remove']))
 {
      foreach ($_POST['id'] as $the_id)
      {
           if (!mysql_query("DELETE FROM videos WHERE id = '$the_id'"))
           {
                echo mysql_error();
           }
      }
 }


 ?>
```

Of course on the header I have the mysql connect query. This is just the php code for listing all videos and try to delete.

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Comment: Are you using a form? You need to have a form for each video.

Comment: Define "nothing happens."  Does the page not post to the server at all?  If that's the case then the problem isn't in the server-side code, it's client-side.  If the page does post to the server, are the expected form values present?  How does the server-side code behave?  Where *specifically* does this fail?

Comment: There is no relationship between your link - `echo "<a href='watch.php?id=$id'>$name</a><br /> ` and your button - `<input type='submit' name='remove' value='Delete'<br />`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks... Well I am learning PHP and on most tutorials they are still using MySQL... But thanks.. will try to switch to mysqli :)

Comment: side note, your delete code should be before your display code, as when you successfully delete a video it will still be shown in the list until you refresh.

Comment: @Sean true... Could you give me some kick help, how to link them together?

Comment: @Jerome If you're just learning PHP, you really should be learning a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). Writing low-level PHP is a lot more work to get anything useful done. Using a framework gives you easy access to a lot of community code that can quickly add significant functionality to your applications.

Comment: @Jerome Did you debug to check that $_POST['id'] is getting the value. And why this foreach?

Comment: @tadman Other codes says, to start just with editor without any framework because it makes it all more complicated.

Comment: Anyone who tells you it's "more complicated" is missing the point. There's a bit of a learning curve, but it's not too bad, and the payoff is considerable. Slamming out code from a bare notepad gives you very quick gains up front, but it quickly degenerates into an unmaintainable mess of quirky code. A framework, if you follow their guidelines, stays orderly much, much longer. It also gives you a ton of features for free, like authentication, XSS protection, better ways of accessing the database, and more.

Comment: @Jerome Where are you posting id (you are using $_POST['id'] not $_GET['id']). You are appending id into the link that you can get by using $_GET['id'] or $_REQUEST['id'] if you are passing the value correctly. As per your code clicking on Submit button will not post the id. Please check your code.

Comment: Most development frameworks are too bloated and do not serve to teach new devs the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of doing this with MySQLi, including binding parameters to avoid SQL injection -

```
if (isset($_POST['remove'])) {
   $remove = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE `id` = ?");

   $vid_id = $_POST['vid_id'];
   $remove->bind_param('s', $vid_id);

   if(!$remove->execute() === true) {
       echo $mysqli->error;               
   }
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `videos`";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
       $id = $row->id;
       $name = $row->name;
       echo "<a href='watch.php?id=$id'>$name</a><br />"; 
       echo "<form name='delete_vid' method='post'>";
       echo "<input type='hidden' name='vid_id' value='$id'>";
       echo "<input type='submit' name='remove' value='Delete'<br />";
       echo "</form>";
    }
} else {
    echo mysqli_error($connection);
}
$result->close();
```

Of course you will have to provide a $connection` to the database, but thsi should get you started not only with MySQLi but with adding a form for each video.

[More on SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I just try your code. But now its not showing any video... Its because I use MySQL on the beginning to connect to the database and your code is MySQLi?

Comment: Agreed @tadman, just want to get the OP started. And yes Jerome, you'll have to modify everything to use the [MySQLi Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Leaving a loaded gun in the middle of the code is a bad idea, especially without any sort of warning.

Comment: I change it now to: $mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database"); but still not showing videos at all.

Comment: @Jerome please read the docs and follow along. Did you select a database after you connected? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Forgot to choose the database... Its showing the links now... But delete button still dosent work... after clicking it, it loads 1 second and nothing... no errors etc..

Comment: I made some changes but you'll want to make sure that I didn't include any typos.

Comment: Thanks... but your code is still to complicated for me, to find it out :( ... since I was learing all time with MySQL and now MySQLi and so much new stuff

Comment: Did you print out the POST array? What does it have in it?

Comment: I was not sure how to use the print_r($_POST), so I added it just under all the code and it says only: Array ( )

Comment: That means that the POST array is empty, which explains why the video is not deleted because we never get into the if statement. I'll modify my code a little and we can check. I've added a method for the form.

Comment: Now we are getting errors:

Notice: Undefined variable: id in /home/videostx/public_html/admin.php on line 54

Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/videostx/public_html/admin.php on line 55

and in the array:

Array ( [vid_id] => 11 [remove] => Delete )

Comment: Cool, the array is now being populated! I removed the `'s'` from the parameter binding in my code above, let's see if that works. It looks like all of my typos wiill be fixed by working through this with you.

Comment: Could the error be my var ?
$remove = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE id = '$id'");

I am really really thank you for going with me to it... learning new stuff is hard... and learning php is for me pretty complicated because you not only learn php, if not mysqli and mostly javascript to..

Comment: You're welcome, we'll get this done. :) Did you make the change that I made above on the bound parameter?

Comment: New error is:

Notice: Undefined variable: vid_id in /home/videostx/public_html/admin.php on line 55

Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() in /home/videostx/public_html/admin.php on line 55

Comment: Well still errors:

Notice: Undefined variable: id in /home/videostx/public_html/admin.php on line 54

Notice: Undefined variable: vid_id in /home/videostx/public_html/admin.php on line 55

Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() in /home/videostx/public_html/admin.php on line 55

Comment: Look at the switch I made above - I tried to bind the param before it was set. My bad - typed it out too quickly.

Comment: Getting this errors now:

Notice: Undefined variable: id in /home/videostx/public_html/admin.php on line 54

Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() in /home/videostx/public_html/admin.php on line 57

Comment: Let's add the `'s'` back in. I also added backticks around ``id`` because it is a column.

Comment: Makes  sure to read the docs here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php. The `'s'` is for string type. Please accept the answer by clicking the check box next to it :)

Comment: Thanks again! But how is the best way to learn php? I mean If I look at mysqli... its like a whole own language :D

Comment: @JayBlanchard one small question... Do you know If I can combinate our code with example: $deleteftp = ftp_delete($ftp_conn, $id); ? Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to combine the code easily, just make sure you have error checking on. Places like http://codecademy.com have lessons in PHP (free) but may only cover the basics. The best way is to learn by doing. There are also several good books on PHP on the market.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I am learning by doing and its working pretty well.. most of time its logical errors... Now my array is showing: Array ( [vid_id] => 13 [file] => btc.mp4 [deleteftp] => Delete FTP ) , I added another button (Delete from FTP).

Comment: You can comment that out if you need to, it was for test purposes.

Comment: I know thats why I am still using it.. its shows all well the file etc... but its not deleting it :)

Comment: Because you're not setting `$_POST['remove']` :)

Comment: Ill have add it in the same $_POST... getting:

Warning: ftp_delete() [function.ftp-delete]: Could not delete 14: No such file or directory in /home/videostx/public_html/admin.php on line 65

Comment: Trying with this code:  $deleteftp = ftp_delete($ftp_conn, $name);

Comment: You may want to start a new question.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I cant open a new question thats the problem... with low rep you always need to wait and wait...

Comment: I'd hate for you to edit this question with the new information, that wouldn't be quite right. There are many ways to gain rep, have you considered doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in the html, each delete button must be in and independent form, with a hidden input with the id too.

```
echo "<a href='watch.php?id=$id'>$name</a><br /> 
    <form method='post'><input type='hidden' value='$id'><input type='submit' name='remove' value='Delete'<br /></form>";
```

Comment: Thanks! I try it, but its not working... It load the page for 1 second and nothing happens.. and entry are still in MySQL

Comment: The hidden input needs a name -> `<input name='id' type='hidden' value='$id'>`

Comment: Even when I give the input a name like you say, it dosent work. :(

Answer (score -1):

```
<form method="post" >
<?php

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `videos`");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];

    echo "<a href='watch.php?id=$id'>$name</a><br /> 
    <button name='id' value='".$id."' type='submit' >Delete</button>
    <br />";
 }


           if (!mysql_query("DELETE FROM videos WHERE id = '".$_POST['id']."'"))
           {
                echo mysql_error();
           } else {
               echo 'successfully deleted';
           }



 ?>
 </form>
```

Comment: **WARNING** This will cause EVERY video to be deleted!

Comment: If you're going to provide an answer please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Using `$_GET` parameters for delete operations is **extremely bad**. Some browsers will pre-fetch these links, and then you'll have a very bad day. Additionally, without escaping, this is completely reckless.